# Open Browser/URL with default browser

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to open an URL with my default browser.

I tried to use "`Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -url" & strUrl, 1)`" but firefox wont open the URL. Instead firefox is starting with my default page.

When i use "`Call Shell(strURL,1)`" im getting a "File not found" Error.

```
Private Sub openurl_Click()
    Dim urlopen As String
    Dim User As String
    Dim pass As String

        urlopen = URL.Value
        User = Username.Value
        'pass = Passwort.Value
        pass = InputBox("Passwort eingeben")
        strUrl = "https://" & User & ":" & pass & "@" & urlopen

        'MsgBox strURL <- TEST OUTPUT

        'Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -t" & strUrl, 1)
        'Call Shell(strURL, 1)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

I got a solution. Maybe its interesting for someone here.

```
    Private Sub openurl_Click()
    Dim urlopen As String
    Dim User As String
    Dim pass As String

        urlopen = URL.Value
        User = Username.Value
        'pass = Passwort.Value
        pass = InputBox("Passwort eingeben")
        strURL = "cmd /c start https://" & User & ":" & pass & "@" & urlopen

        'MsgBox strURL <- Test Output

        Call Shell(strURL, 1)

End Sub
```

i added `cmd /c start` to the `strURL` String

```
strURL = "cmd /c start https://" & User & ":" & pass & "@" & urlopen
```

it seems to be a "dirty" solution but it works :D

Answer (score 1):

Try `Application.FollowHyperlink` instead of `Call Shell`

```
Application.FollowHyperlink strURL
```

Comment: Run Time Error 16388. Cant follow hyperlink

Comment: Which string did you use as strURL? It should start with "https://", not "cmd" etc. So, `Application.FollowHyperlink "https://www.google.com"` will open default browser. As URL you can use anything else, including file names

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I handle this in my Access apps, with 100% success so far.
It directly calls the windows API shell32.dll

**1. Create a module and add this :**

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Open an external application - Advanced way
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Declare Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal FileName As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
  ) As Long


'------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Open Webpage in default browser
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Sub OpenUrl(strURL)
    Dim lSuccess As Long
    lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", strURL)
End Sub
```

**2. From your code, open your URLs like this:**

```
OpenUrl "http://anything.com"
```

---

You can further expand the `ShellExecute` function to open anything else and not only URLs

Comment: MS Access keeps one saying that this solution doesn't work on 64-bits. How to fix this?